# Confirming,with Event::fake() no events (of any type) were fired

Tags: laravel, events, tdd

Larvel provides **Event::assertDispatched** and **Event::assertNotDispatched** methods, which both take an instance of the event class being tested for.  But for events, there doesn't seem to be anything like *Mail::assertNothingSent()* or *Notification::assertNothingSent()*.

Is there a way in Laravel to easily assert (using the fake functionality they provide) to assert that no events, what so ever, where dispatched?

I'm using Laravel version: 5.8.36

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Alex, I'm using laravel version 5.8.36

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a way to check if a mailable has not been sent? If so you have `assertNothingSent()` and `assertNotSent()`, would they work for you? Here's a link to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#mail-fake

Or are you looking for something more general than only checking for a mailable?

Comment: No, I'm aware that mail and notifications allow you to see if nothing (at all) were dispatched/sent.  I'm looking to see if it's possible to confirm that no events (at all) were dispatched (so similar functionality to mail, but for events)